# Wordpress - How do I display the output of a custom field when value is "Array" in the WP dashboard?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, forms, custom-fields

I'm developing a survey site with Wordpress and I'm using Calderawp forms for the main collection tool.  I have a processor in the form that saves the responses for each field in the survey to a custom field within a custom post type.  In this case, the custom post type is "Submissions".

My concern is that when multi-select fields are submitted, such as checkboxes, the value of the custom field in the Wordpress dashboard is "Array":
[image: View of one of my custom fields within the "submission" post]

**My question is how do I output the value of the array in a string or list?**

I thought I might do something like the following, but it's not working.

```
/** 
 * Alter output of custom fields 
 */
add_filter( 'get_post_metadata', 'custom_get_post_metadata_filter', 10, 4 );
function custom_get_post_metadata_filter( $value, $object_id, $meta_key, $single ){

    var_dump($value);

    if( is_array($value) ) { 
        return implode( ',', $value ); 
    }

    return $value;
}
```

The problem may be that every `var_dump($value)` returns `NULL` rather than the array it says it is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

This post explains get_post_meta very well, wordpress should be unserializing the data for you

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/245478/whats-the-point-of-get-post-metas-single-param

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I think get_post_meta is for output the value of this array on the front end, or to the client.  The issue is that I need to see the contents of the array in this metabox in the Wordpress dashboard.  Any ideas?